# Execute function regardless of activity finish

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Currently, I am making an Android app based on Kotlin.
A problem occurred while I was working, and the problem is that I need to use a function that runs regardless of the end of the activity, but I don't know how.
To explain with reference to the picture I inserted, the function is called and executed in Activity 1, and Activity 1 is terminated(finish()), but the called function must be executed, and this should be possible even when calling functions in Activity 2 and Activity 3.
As a result of my searching for this, I am stuck on using a coroutine. Please check if the results are correct.
For reference, the function that should be executed is a countdown timer that runs even when the app is closed.

[image]

funtion(start_timer)

```
fun start_timer() {
    if(mTimerRunning){
    }
    else {
        startTimer()
    }
}
//timer_zone
private fun startTimer() {
    mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis
    mCountDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished
            updateCountDownText()
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            My_App_Data.check_heart +=1
            mTimerRunning = false
            //
            resetTimer()
            if(My_App_Data.check_heart <5){
                startTimer()
            }
            else{
            }

        }
    }.start()
    mTimerRunning = true
}

private fun pauseTimer() {
    mCountDownTimer!!.cancel()
    mTimerRunning = false
}

private fun resetTimer() {
    mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS
    updateCountDownText()
    //check_heart+=1
}

private fun updateCountDownText() {
    val minutes = (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000).toInt() / 60
    val seconds = (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000).toInt() % 60
    val timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    //mTextViewCountDown!!.text = timeLeftFormatted
    My_App_Data.reset_heart_timer =timeLeftFormatted


}


override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    val prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = prefs.edit()
    editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis)
    editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning)
    editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime)
    editor.apply()
    if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
        mCountDownTimer!!.cancel()
    }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
    mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS)
    mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false)
    updateCountDownText()
    if (mTimerRunning) {
        mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0)
        mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 0) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = 0
            mTimerRunning = false
            updateCountDownText()
        } else {
            startTimer()
        }
    }
}

companion object {
    private const val START_TIME_IN_MILLIS: Long = 10000
}
```

Comment: A coroutine won't be guaranteed to complete after an Activity finishes. Use WorkManager or a Service.

Answer (score 1):

This is deferred work with guarantee you are describing. For this Android official documentation recommend the `WorkManager`. Consider using it for as it was designed to able to complete tasks in the background regardless of if Activity is in he foreground or app is killed.

> See [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager)

> > "WorkManager is a library used to enqueue deferrable work that is guaranteed to execute sometime after its Constraints are met. "